# Save as Table in Hive : Failure with exception 'atleast one column must be specified for the table'

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a simple spark job that splits the words from a file and loads into a table in hive.

```
  public static void wordCountJava7() {
    // Define a configuration to use to interact with Spark
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("Work Count App");
    SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
    // Create a Java version of the Spark Context from the configuration
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);

    // Load the input data, which is a text file read from the command line
    JavaRDD<String> input = jsc.textFile("file:///home/priyanka/workspace/ZTA/spark/src/main/java/sample.txt");

    // Java 7 and earlier
    JavaRDD<String> words = input.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
      public Iterable<String> call(String s) {
        return Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
      }
    });

    // Java 7 and earlier: transform the collection of words into pairs (word and 1)
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
      public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
        return new Tuple2(s, 1);
      }
    });

    // Java 7 and earlier: count the words
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> reducedCounts = counts.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
      public Integer call(Integer x, Integer y) {
        return x + y;
      }
    });

    HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc);
    DataFrame dataFrame = hiveContext.createDataFrame(words, SampleBean.class);
    dataFrame.write().saveAsTable("Sample");

    words.saveAsTextFile("output");
    jsc.close();
  }
```

The spark jobs fails with the following trace:

```
  16/04/29 15:41:21 WARN HiveContext$$anon$2: Could not persist `sample` in a Hive compatible way. Persisting it into Hive metastore in Spark SQL specific format.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: at least one column must be specified for the table
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:677)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(ClientWrapper.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.liftedTree1$1(ClientWrapper.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.retryLocked(ClientWrapper.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.createTable(ClientWrapper.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.createDataSourceTable(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.CreateMetastoreDataSourceAsSelect.run(commands.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
```

Checked the table sample in Hive. It did have one column

```
hive> desc sample;
OK
word                    string                  None                
Time taken: 0.218 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

When i try to save it as a table, this error is thrown.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

it means columns data type is not correct
i got same error while using sing Avro schema

in dataframe data type was decimal(20,2)
and in Avro schema I had mentioned type as Decimal(20,2)
it gave same error

[schema with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRk5q.png)

later changed data type in Avro schema to string and it worked fine for me
as Avro convert internal decimal to string
[changed schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkVMo.png)

Answer (score 0):

This issue occured for me because I was doing

```
DataFrameWriter<Row> dfw =
        sparkSession.createDataFrame(jsc.parallelize(uuids), CustomDataClass.class).write();
```

And I fixed it by doing

```
DataFrameWriter<Row> dfw =
        sparkSession.createDataFrame(uuids, CustomDataClass.class).write();
```

(No need to parallelize). Or, in general, make sure the Bean Class you pass matches the type in the List you pass to createDataFrame.